# «Цифровой» посол: как нужно оформить кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

> В Дании впервые в мире появится так называемый «цифровой» посол для
>   установления отношений с крупными корпорациями США, сообщает портал
>   Local.

Новость взята из СМИ. Почему выделяется только одного слово («цифровой»), а не вся фраза «цифровой посол». Или такой подход уместен только при выборочном цитировании отдельных фраз?

Предполагаю также, что наличие фразы «так называемый» не позволяет выделить последующие слова в кавычки (кроме случаев подчеркивания ироничности следующего слова).

> Не заключаются в кавычки слова, следующие за словосочетанием так
>   называемый. Исключение составляют случаи, когда эти слова употреблены
>   в необычном или ироническом значении. gramota.ru

Как оформляются тогда кавычки в этом случае, когда нет фразы «так называемый»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант: В Дании впервые в мире появится так называемый **«цифровой посол"** для установления отношений с крупными корпорациями США, сообщает портал Local.

1)   "Цифровой посол" желательно заключить в кавычки, так как всё словосочетание носит **условный характер**. Дело в том, что слово "посол" не имеет видовой классификации, это всегда дипломатический представитель высшего ранга.

**Пример:** [В Дании появится первый в мире «цифровой посол»](https://php.ru/news/468130)

**2) О кавычках**

Розенталь [Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация | modernlib.ru](http://modernlib.ru/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_19/)

Примечание. При словосочетании **так называемый** последующие слова в кавычки **не заключаются.** **Исключение** составляют случаи, когда эти слова употреблены в **необычном или ироническом значении.**

"Цифровой посол" ―  это как раз необычный термин.

**Дополнение**

Вообще говоря, после "так называемый" кавычки не ставятся в том случае, когда автор говорит **о малоизвестном для широкого круга названии,** но это название **не имеет условного или необычного  характера,** например:

Рядом с нею стоял плетёный сарайчик, **так называемый омшаник**, куда ставят улья на зиму. [И. С. Тургенев. Живые мощи (1874)]

Comment: А почему "амшаник"? Разве не "омшаник"? Это же диалектное от "мох".

Comment: Да, наверное, омшаник ("амшаник" я скопировала  из Нацкорпуса). Омша́ник (зимовник) — утеплённое помещение для зимовки пчёл. Внесено исправление.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в исходной фразе всё верно, в кавычки следует взять только слово "цифровой", потому что именно оно имеет необычный характер.

Слово "посол" употреблено в прямом значении - дипломат, помогающий наладить связи с иностранными государствами, но в данном случае - с цифровыми корпорациями, которые имеют влияние, равное государствам. Пока нет термина "цифровой посол", нет такой должности, возможно, и не будет, по-другому назовут, поэтому необычное слово в кавычках, а перед ним "так называемый" - тоже указание на неофициальность такого названия. А вот если "так называемый" не будет, возможно и всю должность закавычить - как цитату или как необычное название должности.